# Row mainAxisAlignment not working with FittedBox

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Row mainAxisAlignment is not working after wrapping with FittedBox
Please explain me why this is happening.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Container(
          height: 20,
          child: FittedBox(
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                Text('THis is the thing'),
                Text('THis is another thing'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )
    );
  }
```

Expected

[image]

Output

[image]

Comment: Just remove `FittedBox`, why do you need that?

Comment: i am using strings of variable lengths, and I need to fit that string into the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use `Row` inside `FittedBox` with effect of mainAxisAllignment.spaceBetween or any, you have to manually set spaceBetween using `SizedBox` with width as per spacing. Also set fit property to `BoxFit.fitHeight` .

```
Container(
          height: 20,
            child: FittedBox(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Text('THis is the thing',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),),
                  SizedBox(width: 300,),
                  Text('THis is another thing',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20,),),
                ],
              ),
            ),
        )
```

*Note: Set allignment property to specify positioning. for `MainAxisAllignment.start` and `MainAxisAllignment.start`.
Eg: `Alignment.topLeft` to get `MainAxisAllignment.start` effect.*

Comment: okay, seems like SizedBox is the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question,

> Row `mainAxisAlignment` is not working after wrapping with `FittedBox`
> Please explain me why this is happening.

`Container` always fills the entire width of the screen size. If it has child, then it will wraps up itself to match the width of its child.

Another interesting widget `FittedBox` will fits its children based on the size of the children within itself by scaling based on available space.

**Solution**

To achieve the expected result, you can force set the `width` of `Container` widget to `double.infinity`

[image]

**Snippet**

```
body: Container(
          height: 20,
          width: double.infinity,
          child: FittedBox(
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [Text('THis is the ROW'), Text('THis is another  ')],
            ),
          ),
        )
```

*NOTE : If texts are small it will be enlarged to occupy the rest of the space because it is inside the `FittedBox` and vice-versa.*

Comment: Sorry but it's still not supporting the spaceBetween in Row, and the result has not improved

Comment: If you need a space in between the texts , place your `Row` widget out of `FittedBox`.

Answer (score -1):

wrap it with align:

```
Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                          child: FittedBox(
                            fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                                  child: Text("hello")),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
```